# In Perl, how to match two consecutive Carriage Returns?

Tags: regex, windows, perl, match, carriage-return

Hi StackOverflow buddies,

I'm on **Windows platform**;  I have a data file but something wrong happened and (I don't know why) all combinations of "Carriage Return + New Line" became "Carriage Return + Carriage Return + New Line", **(190128 edit:)** for example:

When viewing the file as plain text, it is:

[image: Text file in plain text (with unprintable stuffs)]

When viewing the same file in hex mode, it is:

[image: Text file in hex mode, can see the double "0D"s]

Out of practical purposes I need to remove the extra "0D" in double "0D"s like "`.... 30 30 0D 0D 0A 30 30 ....`", and change it to "`.... 30 30 0D 0A 30 30 ....`".

**190129 edit:** Besides, to ensure that my problem can be reproduced, I uploaded my data file to GitHub at URL (should download & unzip it before using; in a binary \ hex editor you can `0D 0D 0A` in the first line): https://github.com/katyusza/hello_world/blob/master/ram_init.zip

I used the following Perl script to remove the extra Carriage Return, but to my astonishment my regex just do NOT work!! My entire code is (**190129 edit**: past entire Perl script here):

```
use warnings            ;
use strict              ;
use File::Basename      ;

#-----------------------------------------------------------
# command line handling, file open \ create
#-----------------------------------------------------------

# Capture input input filename from command line:
my $input_fn = $ARGV[0] or
die "Should provide input file name at command line!\n";

# Parse input file name, and generate output file name:
my ($iname, $ipath, $isuffix) = fileparse($input_fn, qr/\.[^.]*/);
my $output_fn = $iname."_pruneNonPrintable".$isuffix;

# Open input file:
open (my $FIN, "<", $input_fn) or die "Open file error $!\n";

# Create output file:
open (my $FO, ">", $output_fn) or die "Create file error $!\n";


#-----------------------------------------------------------
# Read input file, search & replace, write to output
#-----------------------------------------------------------

# Read all lines in one go:
$/ = undef;

# Read entire file into variable:
my $prune_txt = <$FIN> ;

# Do match & replace:
 $prune_txt =~ s/\x0D\x0D/\x0D/g;          # do NOT work.
# $prune_txt =~ s/\x0d\x0d/\x30/g;          # do NOT work.
# $prune_txt =~ s/\x30\x0d/\x0d/g;          # can work.
# $prune_txt =~ s/\x0d\x0d\x0a/\x0d\x0a/gs; # do NOT work.

# Print end time of processing:
print $FO $prune_txt  ;

# Close files:
close($FIN)     ;
close($FO)      ;
```

I did everything I could to match two consecutive Carriage Returns, but failed. Can anyone please point out my mistake, or tell me the right way to go? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you think you have two carriage returns next to each other?

Comment: Replace `[\r\n]+` with `\r\n` as shown [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/ZywcuC/1). Here's the [CODE](https://regex101.com/r/ZywcuC/1/codegen?language=perl)

Comment: @zdim I can see two carriage returns when I view the file in binary format.

Comment: Presumably you saved the edited text? Are you accessing the input/output files in binary mode?

Comment: I did save the edited text; besides, when I try matching other keyword it did work.

Comment: Run under the Perl debugger and inspect your string inside Perl.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong (for Windows), but you shouldn't notice anything with extra `\r`s (when they're back to back) ...?  For a whole extra empty line you need an extra linefeed, not just `\r`, no?

Comment: For what OS is this Perl built? Did you forget to account for CRLF<->LF translation in Windows?

Comment: @zdim Extra `\r`s may not cause trouble for a human reader, but I'm reading the data file in another program (Verilog's $readmemh) so that every ASCII code matters.

Comment: @katyusza OK.  I meant to say that what you are seeing may not be due to doubled `\r` -- with doubled `\r` you _wouldn't_ see that (I think?).  Perhaps there is really more hiding there (while there is a reason why that shows in your hex output)?

Comment: @ikegami This Perl is built and run on Windows; the text file in question was also created on Windows. However, in my understanding, a Perl script should always be able to do regex match & replace ASCII combinations on a file, whether it's Linux or Windows format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, file handles have a `:crlf` layer given to them by default.

- This layer converts CR LF to LF on read.
- This layer converts LF to CR LF on write.

**Solution 1: Compensate for the `:crlf` layer.**

You'd use this solution if you want to end up with system-appropriate line endings.

```
# ... read ...      # CR CR LF ⇒ CR LF
s/\r+\n/\n/g;       # CR LF    ⇒ LF
# ... write ...     # LF       ⇒ CR LF
```

**Solution 2: Remove the `:crlf` layer.**

You'd use this solution if you want to end up with CR LF unconditionally.

Use `<:raw` and `>:raw` instead of `<` and `>` as the mode.

```
# ... read ...      # CR CR LF ⇒ CR CR LF
s/\r*\n/\r\n/g;     # CR CR LF ⇒ CR LF
# ... write ...     # CR LF    ⇒ CR LF
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your post clarified my misunderstanding about file format and solved my problem! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The first of your regexes appears to work fine for me, which means that there may be an issue in some other piece of code. Please provide a [Minimal, **Complete, and Verifiable** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which means including sample input data and so on.

```
$ perl -wMstrict -e 'print "Foo\r\r\nBar\r\r\n"' >test.txt
$ hexdump -C test.txt 
00000000  46 6f 6f 0d 0d 0a 42 61  72 0d 0d 0a              |Foo...Bar...|
0000000c
$ cat test.pl 
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dump;

my $filename = 'test.txt';
open my $fh, '<:raw:encoding(ASCII)', $filename or die "$filename: $!";
my $prune_txt = do { local $/; <$fh> }; # slurp file
close $fh;

dd $prune_txt;
$prune_txt =~ s/\x0D\x0D/\x0D/g;
dd $prune_txt;

$ perl test.pl
"Foo\r\r\nBar\r\r\n"
"Foo\r\nBar\r\n"
```

By the way, it's not immediately obvious to me which encoding your file is using? In the above example, you may need to adjust the `:encoding(...)` layer appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Upon your kind suggestion I already updated my post, put my entire Perl script in it, and added a URL pointing to my original data file, ensuring that my question can be reproduced. My data file was created on Windows, and my Perl also runs on Windows, does it mean they'rea all "Windows encoding"?

Comment: @katyusza Thanks for the update. It looks like you're not opening the file with the `:raw` layer, which would remove the `:crlf` that is automatically added on Windows, which is why my code worked on my end. I'm pretty sure using `<:raw:encoding(...)` should work for you too, in that you'll get the original CR/CR/LF sequences that you could then fix in your code.

Comment: Buddy thank you for your futher follow-up! I didn't know that Windows would AUTOMATICALLY ADD stuffs in my file WITHOUT LETTING ME KNOW THAT, and now I know this :) My problem is solved now, thank you for your careful explanations!

Comment: @katyusza Glad to help. Just to make sure it's clear, it's not exactly Window's fault - by "`:crlf`" I meant Perl's I/O layer by that name, which Perl automatically uses on Windows in an attempt to be helpful with reading and writing text files with CRLF line endings on Windows. For more information, see [Newlines in perlport](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#Newlines) and [PerlIO](http://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO.html).