# How to match CR CR LF newline pattern

Tags: regex, awk, grep, newline

In Windows 10 environment I have to check how many CSV files (separator is ";") in a directory have this odd newline pattern: CR CR LF (or \r\r\n if you prefer).
However, I can match `\r\r` neither with grep nor with awk. On awk I've also tried to change `RS` to be `;` and `FS` a not-used character (`#`), but apparently awk matches single CR, not CR CR. So awk in Windows sees CR CR LF as CR LF and FNR output a number of records equal to any other "normal end-line" file.
Strange thing is that with Notepad++ I can clearly see CR CR LF (causing an extra line break, as e.g. in Excel) and with built-in regex finder, search for `\r\r\n` match all the lines. Is it not possible to force awk to act on a raw text file without removing some CR?
The file is like this (I've simplified a little): 5 lines with 4 x fields separated by `;` and a the end of each line CRCRLF. Opening with Notepad++ (and Excel) I see 10 lines.

I hoped that the following GNU awk script would return `16 5`

```
BEGIN {RS = ";";FS = "#"; linecount = 0}
/\r\r/ {linecount = linecount + 1}
END {print FNR, linecount}
```

However, it returns `16 0`. If I search to match `/\r/` instead, I obtain `16 5`.

So basically I'm afraid that Windows CMD shell is stripping out one of the two consecutive CR (or to say it better, is replacing a CR LF pair with LF) before passing stream to gawk, I was wondering if it is possible to avoid this, because I want to use gawk to detect how many files have this weird CR CR LF newline.

I believe a very similar question has been posted here:
[In Perl, how to match two consecutive Carriage Returns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54396278/in-perl-how-to-match-two-consecutive-carriage-returns)

Comment: No, my problem is CR CR LF pattern and I'm no using CYGWIN. I've installed gawk by mean of GOW package. However apparently the only solution is to be aware that on CR CR LF, a CR LF token is replaced by LF from Windows before passing data stream to gawk and then if some "single" CR are still there, this means that is a "weird" newline file type. I was just hoping gawk offered to parse original .txt file the same way Notepad++ is apparently able to do.

Answer (score 1):

**After realizing there is a duplicate (thanks @tripleee):**

> Under MS-Windows, gawk (and many other text programs) silently translates end-of-line `\r\n` to `\n` on input and `\n` to `\r\n` on output. A special `BINMODE` variable (c.e.) allows control over these translations and is interpreted as follows:
>
> - If `BINMODE` is "r" or one, then binary mode is set on read (i.e., no translations on reads).
> - If `BINMODE` is "w" or two, then binary mode is set on write (i.e., no translations on writes).
> - If `BINMODE` is "rw" or "wr" or three, binary mode is set for both read and write.
> - `BINMODE=non-null-string` is the same as `BINMODE=3` (i.e., no translations on reads or writes). However, gawk issues a warning message if the string is not one of "rw" or "wr".
>
> **<sub>source: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#PC-Using</sub>**

To keep awk in its original POSIX-style, you should use `BINMODE=3`. Using awk (or any unmodified version), you should easily be able to do it by checking if the record ends with `\r\r`. This is because awk defaultly0 splits a file in records using `RS="\n"`. As GOW is using GNU awk, you have the following options:

**count files:**

```
awk '/\r\r$/{f++; nextfile} END {print f,"files match"}' BINMODE=3 *.csv
```

**count files and print filename:**

```
awk '/\r\r$/{f++; print FILENAME; nextfile} END {print f,"files match"}' BINMODE=3 *.csv
```

**count files, print filename and lines:**

```
awk '(FNR==1){if (c) {print fname, c; f++}; c=0; fname=FILENAME}
     /\r\r$/{c++}
     END { print f,"files match" }' BINMODE=3 *.csv
```

**note:** remove `BINMODE=3` on any POSIX system.

Comment: Yeah, this is a better, efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try GNU grep's `-z` and `-P` switch, try this:

```
grep -zcP "\r\r\n" *.csv | awk -F: "$2{c++}END{print c}"
```

So I created a file like you said by this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ORS="\r\r\n"; OFS=";"; for(i=1;i<11;i++)print "aa","bb","cc",i>"strange.csv"}'
```

And I can search `\r\r\n` in the csv files like this:

```
> grep -zcP "\r\r\n" *.csv
file1.csv:0
file2.csv:0
file3.csv:0
file_a.csv:0
file_b.csv:0
results.csv:0
strange.csv:1
```

And combine it with `awk`:

```
awk -F: "$2{c++}END{print c}"
```

to get the count:

```
> grep -zcP "\r\r\n" *.csv | awk -F: "$2{c++}END{print c}"
1
```

**OR**, just use `awk` alone:

```
> awk 'BEGIN{RS="";}/\r\r\n/{c++;nexfile}END{print c}' *.csv
1
```

So both above `grep` and `awk` examples, read whole file instead of dealing with each line every turn.

Comment: Thank you Tiw,  your grep suggestion was the one I was looking for, unfortunately  I got this response grep: The -P and -z options cannot be combined. I'm using GNU grep 2.5.4 under a CMD shell in Win10.

Comment: @atcher  Then it's better to upgrade it :)  fyi, I'm using GNU grep 3.0